# how to show * after enter the value in uitext filed

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am working on `otp` secret app.In that user will get 7 digit `otp` number and they will enter in 7 `UITextField` in my app. So what I need is , when user type the value in first text field and when user move to second text field I want to change my first text field value to ' * '. For secret purpose.

How to do this in `UITextField` ??? I am using swift 3.0

Comment: so you don't want to use secure entry, you just want to replace the text? did you try just replacing the text?

Comment: I tried `func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.text = "*"
        
    }
`

Comment: and was it called? you need to give more details...

Comment: But there is one clear button, which will clear all data in all text field.But some time if i click any uitext field ,this ' * '  symbol is automatically appearing there

Comment: You can set the property `secureTextEntry` to true. For example `yourTextField.secureTextEntry = true`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your textField in Storyboard check this:

[image]

When you press any text, it will show *

Answer (score 1):

Please use secure UIText field or look at UITextFieldDelegate here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/